# how to check the value of display property of a header element?

Tags: javascript

I need to check the display property of a header element on the page. Based on it different operations are to be done. I tried using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display
```

and comparing it to various display attributes, but this is executing false part whatever property I check for.
Here is my html :

```
<body>
    <header id="main">
        <p>Test to find the display property of an element (header in this case).</p>
    </header>
</body>
```

And here is my Javascript :

```
var test1 = document.createElement('div');
var test2 = document.createElement('div');

test1.innerText = 'Testing for block : ';
test2.innerText = 'Testing for none : ';

var body = document.getElementById('main');

if (document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display == 'block') {
    test1.innerText = test1.innerText + 'true part is executed';
    body.appendChild(test1);
} else {
    test1.innerText = test1.innerText + 'false part is executed';
    body.appendChild(test1);
}

if (document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display == 'none') {
    test2.innerText = test2.innerText + 'true part is executed';
    body.appendChild(test2);
} else {
    test2.innerText = test2.innerText + 'false part is executed';
    body.appendChild(test2);
}
```

I put this also on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n8zDc/1/

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: A `<header>` element has a default display style of `inline`, so testing for none or block won't help much.

Comment: And `element.style` doesn't get the default styles, only set styles.

Comment: I am getting confused by your first comment. I tried testing it myself and found out that it is indeed `block` instead of `inline` as you suggested. Can you explain why ? I updated the fiddle I earlier mentioned. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/n8zDc/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle). You haven't defined a `display` property value anywhere in the DOM

```
var header = document.getElementById('main');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(header);
console.log(style.display);
```

The reason is that `.style` doesn't really compute which style is actually applied to the element, but simply the style attribute on the DOM (either the HTML, or applied through JavaScript). As an example, consider this CSS:

```
* {
  float: right;
}

.foo {
  float: left;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div>Foo</div>
<div class='foo'>Bar</div>
```

Neither of these have any `style` values in them, yet their computed styles will have a bunch of values, browser defaults such as `display: block`, and the CSS rules applied to them.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Thanks for putting everything so clearly.